# How to change users picture in windows 10 of others users being administrator

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, user-profiles, avatar

I know how to change my own user.

I want to know how to change the users picture without having to have to login into each account.

I have Windows 10.

My question is not answered in [Windows 7 in enterprise - What about the account picture?](https://superuser.com/questions/598752/windows-7-in-enterprise-what-about-the-account-picture). There it explains how to not permit users to change their own pictures. I want to change users pictures. Neither in [Change user account picture](https://superuser.com/questions/199795/change-user-account-picture)

Comment: Mabey some insight here....http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/152658-user-logon-display-picture-set-default-all-users.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 in enterprise - What about the account picture?](http://superuser.com/questions/598752/windows-7-in-enterprise-what-about-the-account-picture)

Comment: @Ramhound. In that post it descrives how to not permit the users to change theirs pictures. I need to change the users pictures one by one.

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer - The answer also explains how to change the user profile though, by providing a link, to another question with an answer.  The user must exists, but the location of the profile picture, is well documented.  For whatever reason the picture is stored at `C:\Users\Public\Public Account Pictures\...`

Comment: Yes. But it says "every user will have the same picture". I am asking how to change individuals pictures.

Comment: @Ramound, Can you delete the sing "This question may already have an answer here:"? I think that with that sign, others that can help me don't read my question thinking that I'm asking a question that already has a good anwer. But it does not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change account picture of DIFFERENT user in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/1061083/150988)  —  but it doesn’t have an answer either.